# Excel histogram with discrete "bin numbers"

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a column of data similar to this:

```
1
1
1
1
1.2
1.2
1.2
2
2
2.1
2.2
3
3
3
3
4
```

I want excel to display how many 1 values, how many 1.2 values, how many 2 values, etc. I know I should use Histogram for that, but it asks for bin range, and I don't want bins, I just want it to tell me how many of each values are there, not how many between 1 and 2, 2 and 3, etc, but how many ones, how many twos etc. If I ommit bin range, it uses it's own bins. 
How do I do that?

Comment: Off the top of my head, you could brute force it.  0.1 is the smallest increment, so create a histogram with a bin increment of 0.1.  It will give you a ton of bins, but only the ones with actual values will be non-zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netismine, try creating a pivot table and charting the data then.

[image]

Comment: Disregard this - how did you get the count of data column? I only have the first one

Comment: Scratch that, found it!

Comment: Is this an adequate solution?